# trying update checkbox value in a rails index with ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Needing a little help with this ajax code to change a boolean column in a index.html.erb in a checkbox when click, in a rails app. I'm new in javascript.

```
<% @budget_histories.each do |budget_history| %>
 <tr>
  <li class="checkbox m-b-15">
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAllBudgetHistoryItems(this, '<%= budget_history.id %>');" name="budget_history_items" id="budget_history_item_<%= budget_history.id %>" value="<%= budget_history.id %>" />
    <i class="input-helper"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

```
function checkAllBudgetHistoryItems(el, id) {
    if (el.checked) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/budget_histories/update',
        data: 'budget_history_item_' + id,
        success: function (data) {
          $("#budget_history_items_tbody input").prop('checked', false);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/budget_histories/update',
        data: 'budget_history_item_' + id,
        success: function (data) {
          $("#budget_history_items_tbody input").prop('checked', true);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

How can I update the accept(boolean) attribute from my database with ajax when click the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with something like that:

1. Create a controller method:

```
  def accept_budget    
    if @budget_history.toggle!(:accept)
      render json: {}, status: :ok
    else 
      render json: @budget_history.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

2. Create a route

```
  resources :budget_histories do
    member do
      put :accept_budget
    end
  end
```

3. Checkbox html

```
<li class="checkbox m-b-15">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAllBudgetHistoryItems(this, '<%= budget_history.id %>');" name="budget_history_items" id="budget_history_item_<%= budget_history.id %>" value="<%= budget_history.id %>" />
    <i class="input-helper"></i>
  </label>
</li>
```

4. Edit the script:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function checkAllBudgetHistoryItems(el, id) {
    if (el.checked) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/budget_histories/' + id + '/accept_budget',
        data: 'budget_history_item_' + id,
        success: function (data) {
          $(el).prop('checked', true);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/budget_histories/' + id + '/accept_budget',
        data: 'budget_history_item_' + id,
        success: function (data) {
          $(el).prop('checked', false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```